# Sammyjs and pagerjs routes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, sammy.js, pagerjs

I'm started using a combination of KnockoutJS (2.2.1), SammyJS (0.7.4) and [PagerJS](http://pagerjs.com/) (latest from github with jquery hashchange) to create a single page app and I've run into a problem with the routes as they do not work in Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m or Firefox 16.0 (for some reason it actually works in IE7).

Using sammyjs I've specified the routes that the app should react on and their corresponding actions, for example loading user data. The same routes are used in pagerjs to specify which page to display. For some reason the sammyjs code is executed but not the pagerjs code.

When updating the route, for example going from `#!/` to `#!/user`, pagerjs doesn't switch to the new page, but data is updated as expected when switching between `#!/user?uid=123` and  `#!/user?uid=321` . However, when removing the sammyjs code it works - the switch between pages works but data will of course not update properly.

It seems like SammyJS terminates further execution by pagerjs, but as I'm quite new to these libraries it might very well be my code misbehaving. Greatful for any insights.

The javascript code looks something like this:

```
    var UserModel = function () {

        var self = this;
        self.userId = null;
        self.user = ko.observable();
        self.userid = ko.observable();

        // Load
        self.load = function(userId) {
            self.loadUser(userId);
        };

        // Load user data
        self.loadUser = function(userId) {
        console.log('Loading user data');
        }; 

        // Client-side routes    
        Sammy(function () {

            // Overview - datatables in tabs
            this.get('#!/', function () {
                console.log('Start page');
            });

            // User - details
            this.get('#!/user', function () {
                console.log('user page');
                self.userId = this.params.uid;
                self.load(self.userId);
            });

        }).run();


    }

// Renders user info
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#user-info').length) {
        var userModel = new UserModel(); 
        pager.extendWithPage(userModel);
        ko.applyBindings(userModel);
        // Load initial data via ajax
        userModel.load();
        pager.Href.hash = '#!/';
        pager.startHashChange();
    }
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
```

And here goes the HTML with the pagerjs data-bindings:

```
<div class="container">

    <div data-bind="page: {id: 'start'}">
        Startpage
    </div>

    <div data-bind="page: {id: 'user', params: ['uid']}">
        User page
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Or, instead of Sammy.js, you could just use `withOnShow` parameter of the pager.Page to execute the function to get user data needed for the page as described here: http://pagerjs.com/demo/#!/model/lazy_bind_view_model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working by changing PagerJS to use the naïve history manager instead of jQuery hashchange. In other words this line:

```
pager.startHashChange();
```

was changed to:

```
pager.start();
```

As of magic it also works in IE7 even if the docs at http://pagerjs.com states it doesn't. Well, for me it does work

```
// 1. iff using naïve hashchange - wont work with IE7
pager.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

You need to add

```
this.get(/.*/, function() {
    console.log("this is a catch-all");
});
```

after your last `this.get`. Then Sammy doesn't stop the event.

Comment: Thanks @finnsson! Unfortunately this doesn't work, the event isn't propagating properly. As both SammyJS and PagerJS are supposed to react on the same routes, for example `#!/user`, Sammy stops the event propagation as soon as it matches `#!/user` and pagerjs never gets the chance to fire. The wild card route will only be reached in case no other routes are matching, it's like the `this.notfound`. Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

As long as you include the hashchange plugin pager.start() will use it.

> Is the same as the naïve, but you need to include the jQuery hashchange plugin first.

http://pagerjs.com/demo/#!/navigation/setup